# printing serial date and data to .csv or excel file using fprintf?

Tags: excel, matlab, datetime

I just started using Matlab (R2015a) a few weeks ago, and although I have searched for an answer to this question (and tried a few workarounds) I haven't had any luck. Hopefully, it's an easy fix!!

I am trying to write one column of serial dates at high precision (I need milliseconds) and many columns of data to a .csv file. I don't want insane precision for everything, just the first column of dates.

Here's what I've found: 
- csvwrite doesn't allow for differing precisions.

- xlswrite doesn't have enough precision (even though my serial date is a double, and yes I looked at the spreadsheet cell)
- dlmwrite appends data in row format, so writing the dates and then appending the rest of the data doesn't work (though soooo close!)

Now I'm trying with `fprintf`:

`hz_time` is the serial date (double)
`data1` and `data2` are 4x25 (double) and 4x7 (double) respectively

```
hz_time = 1.0e+05 *
[7.357583607870371, 7.357583607928241, 7.357583607986110, 7.357583608043980]

STR_data = [data1, data2];
filename = (strcat('Processed_',files(k1).name));
file = fopen(filename,'w');
fprintf(file,'%.20f\n',hz_time);   
fprintf(file,'%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%\n',STR_data);
fclose('all')
```

Currently, this code appends data1 and data2 in one cell at the end of the `STR_date_time` column. When I try concatenating `hz_time` and the data matrices together (using `strcat`) I fail:

```
STR_data = strcat([hz_time, data1, data2])
```

> Warning: Out of range or non-integer values truncated during conversion to character.

I'm sure it's probably my formatting...

My end goal is to export this data (into a .csv or excel spreadsheet or something) so that the first column has the serial date (loads of precision) and columns 2-8 have the other data in it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try adding a precision to the format specifier as described in the [documentation of `fprint`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's taken care of with the %.20f bit of my code. The serial time comes out with enough precision, I just can't get the rest of the file to come out correctly.

Comment: You are right, I have over-looked that statement. Something else: In your call to `strcat` you should remove the square-brackets and the input arguments should be string arrays or strings. Still, this won't fix your problem here. Could you edit your answer to include an example of what exactly your final goal is?